# How to change the prop content in a component on button click?

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-props

I click the button and the function call should change the props inside the component. Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we cannot change the props means we can assign them to another value but the component won't be updated.

Also, props should not be changed, they are [read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

If you want to change then do following

- if props is a state in the parent then pass its setter in the child
- else store the prop as a state in a child component

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW-uSq9Gha8) take reference from this video